# SQLite Date Field to JavaScript date object

Tags: javascript, sqlite

I have the string

> January, 01 1900 00:00:00

coming to me from a SQLite database. 
What syntax do I use to convert it to a date object in JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

```
var date = new Date('January, 01 1900 00:00:00');
```